# how to delete rows from databases that share id using another condition like "name" instead of id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, sql-delete

i have tried this in phpmyadmin but it bring this error "#1109 - Unknown table 'training_session' in MULTI DELETE"

I have two tables (`athlete`) and (`training_session`). `athlete`'s relevant columns are `name`, `id` and `training_session`'s relevant column is `athlete_id`.

```
DELETE training_session  FROM training_session t
INNER JOIN athlete a
iN t.athlete_id = a.id
WHERE a.name = ‘Per Persen’;
```

MySQL said:

> 1109 - Unknown table 'training_session' in MULTI DELETE

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alias defined in the `FROM` clause:

```
DELETE t
    FROM training_session t INNER JOIN
         athlete a
         ON t.athlete_id = a.id
WHERE a.name = 'Per Persen';
```